# Tumblr.js official javascript/node API "link" posts with image, title, body

Tags: node.js, api, oauth, tumblr

I'd like to be able to post link posts on a blog exactly the same way as if you were to go on the regular user interface and choose a "link" post and paste in a URL. It automatically grabs the image, sizes it, sets the title and a body/caption.

How do I go about doing this with the tumblr.js api wrapper?

I already have the API working so I do not need to know how to connect/post link articles. I am specifically interested in being able to add link posts that look/work exactly like the link posts you make as a regular user on their web interface. Using the API to do a link post just throws in the title. Using a photo post doesn't allow you to do a separate title/body. I'd love it to look like it does on the website when you paste in a link post and have the tumblr api/feed return it the same way too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response via github issues that explains that what I was attempting to accomplish is not available via the API. It can only be done using a tumblr client.

https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js/issues/41#issuecomment-135588952